# spawnl, shellexecute запуск приложения с атрибутами

Tags: c++

Есть программа с атрибутами. Атрибуты: 1) запускается программа, 2) подхватывается предварительно созданный файл и 3)параметры для него.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Marilou2010\Bin\Exec.exe"
>   /p:"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\right hand_text\ServoMotor\ServoMotor.mdsp"
>   /c:"Normal"

Пытаюсь заставить консоль на с++ запустить ее.
Пытался через spawnl и shellexecute. До этого запускал экзешники через CreateProcess, но они не содержали атрибутов/параметров.

```
spawnl(P_NOWAIT, "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Marilou2010\\Bin\\Exec.exe\" /p:\"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\right hand_text\\ServoMotor\\ServoMotor.mdsp\" /c:\"Normal\"", NULL); 
ShellExecute(NULL, "open","\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Marilou2010\\Bin\\Exec.exe\" /p:\"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\right hand_text\\ServoMotor\\ServoMotor.mdsp\" /c:\"Normal\"", NULL, NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Вопрос то в чём?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну посмотрите, как `spawnl` объявлена...

```
int spawnl(int mode, char *fname, char *arg0, ..., char *argN, NULL)
```

Т.е. по логике, вы должны вызывать как

```
spawnl(P_NOWAIT, 
       "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Marilou2010\\Bin\\Exec.exe", // Запускаемая программа
       "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Marilou2010\\Bin\\Exec.exe", // argv0 - да хоть NULL тут, не так важно...
       "/p:\"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\right hand_text\\ServoMotor\\ServoMotor.mdsp\"",
       "/c:\"Normal\"",
       NULL);
```

(Будем надеяться, что ваша программа правильно отработает кавычки в параметрах).

Что здесь, что в `ShellExecute` вы *смешиваете в кучу* имя выполнимого файла и передаваемые аргументы командной строки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, программа запустилась.